# Where is the location that BDE and ADO DLL's are stored in my System.?

Tags: delphi, ado, bde

i am trying to explore the BDE and ADO in Delphi. Where can i find the BDE and ADO DLL Files so that i can explore what all functions are written in that.Delphi 5 and BDE is already installed in my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BDE:  Traditionally, the main BDE DLL, Idapi32.Dll was installed to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Borland Shared\BDE
```

by the default Delphi install.  I have not installed the BDE onto a recent (Win7/Win10) version of Windows, but would not be surprised if the DLL ended up in SysWOW64.

ADO:  You need to look in the Delphi source file `ADOInt.Pas` to identify the name of the ADO DLL your Delphi version uses.  It will be at the top of the file in a section that looks like this (following is for D7, because I don't have D5 installed):

```
unit ADOInt;

// ********************************************************************* //
// Type Lib: C:\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\SYSTEM\ADO\MSADO15.DLL        //
// IID\LCID: {00000200-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}\0                    //
// PASTLWTR : 1.1                                        //
// HelpString: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library                //
// Version:    2.1                                                       //
// ********************************************************************* //
```

Btw, you need the 32-bit version of MSADO15.DLL, which on my (Win10 64-bit) system is located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado
```

The Delphi source files you need to study to see how Delphi uses thd BDE and ADO are

DBTables.Pas, BDE.Int and SMIntf.Pas for the BDE and ADOInt.Pas and ADODB.Pas for ADO.

As you will see, in the BDE code, there is no exact counterpart to a TAdoConnection, which is why I told you in reply to your other q that you are wasting your time trying to ease conversion by coming up with a connection type which could be used for both.  Sorry to say so, but the fact that you've had to ask this q is a pretty good sign that you are out of your depth trying to come up with a "mixed connection" solution.

Comment: Yeah i understood that a mixed connection is not possible. What i am trying to do now is to write a wrapper class for BDE So that it can use a ADO Connection. is it a feasible solution.?

Comment: It is no more feasible than trying to code a "mixed connection", I'm afraid.  The BDE simply does not have a functional equivalent of a TAdoConnection.  It uses a TSession object and BDE statement handles instead.

Comment: Hi, Does Delphi 7 store the BDE Path in the Win32 Registry ? Can the Win32 Registry accessed by normal User Mode - or only with Admin Rights ? Because, then, I could read out it at Program start ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the default folder for the BDE is
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Borland Shared\BDE
From what I can remember the Delphi 5 installation allows you to chose the folder so it could be different.

As it is a tad old you will have some problems with the BDE. I think it has bugs in it with regard to handling blob fields.

Are you looking at a legacy app that needs the BDE?

I think ADO is a better bet.
Look for unit ADODB.pas and ADODb.dll

Comment: yeah am working on some legacy app. Trying to convert the BDE Connection to ADO. Any Sugessions..?

Comment: The unit the OP needs so as to identify the Ado DLL is ADOInt.Pas, not ADODB.Pas.  And ADBDb.Dll is **not** the relevant DLL, it is a DLL for DotNet.

Comment: Sorry, have not used Delphi 5 in a while. I have seen application that uses both ADO and BDE so you don't have to convert everything all at once. This allows you to initially use ADO in only the places where BDE is giving problems.